# Hide Category Navigation node in Spartacus having a CMS Restrictions

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

### Problem/Wish

I have assigned a loggedInUser Restriction (CMSInverseRestriction) for the ***Film Cameras*** CMSLink Component in Spartacus Electronics Shop. Hence for the anonymous User, the CMS Link is empty. However, the Navigation Node remains without any URL link attached to it (unless the user logs in).

I would have rather liked if the whole CMSNavigationNode was hidden when the corresponding Link is missing (and it has no child nodes too).
I am using the Spartacus 3.RC version with Hybris 2005

### Analysis

After login/logoff the State is refreshed with help of the Metareducers. That could be the reason why after Login, we are able to see that the URL link works

The logic in the template file of **NavigationUIComponent** the node heder is written even though it has no children nor link
Snippet from the NavigationUIComponent Template
'''

```
<cx-generic-link
  *ngIf="
    node.url && (!node.children || node.children?.length === 0);
    else heading
  "
  [url]="node.url"
  [target]="node.target"
  [style]="node.styleAttributes"
  [class]="node.styleClasses"
>
  {{ node.title }}
  <cx-icon
    *ngIf="flyout && node.children?.length > 0"
    [type]="iconType.CARET_DOWN"
  ></cx-icon>
</cx-generic-link>

<ng-template #heading>
  <h5
    [attr.aria-label]="node.title"
    [attr.tabindex]="flyout && (depth === 0 || node.url) ? 0 : -1"
  >
    {{ node.title }}
    <cx-icon
      *ngIf="flyout && node.children?.length > 0"
      [type]="iconType.CARET_DOWN"
    ></cx-icon>
  </h5>
</ng-template>
```

'''

### What has been tried

My intention was to change the logic in the "overridden" NavigationUIComponent so that the "empty" Navigation Node of "***Film Cameras***" is hidden for Anonyous User
Tried to override the NavigationUIComponent, but was not successful (probably there is no direct CMS Mapping). Hence I tried to override the **CategoryNavigationComponent** and then use my "overridden" NavigationUIComponent. But then the UI did not come up good. All the Navigation nodes seems to be stacked-up on top of each other - not sure what I missed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn1OP.png)

### Help

The way I have tried does not look so convincing as the UI is not looking good with the stacked up Navvigation. Could you please help me with a better way to bring on this functionality. Or maybe some tips to fix this problem with the UI